# Is there a way to get column info on any given query in sql?

Tags: sql

My problem is, that I would like to get column names and types etc... not only from one table or a view, but from any select query. For example when joining 2 tables.

If the select query looked like this:

```
Select * from employees
```

Then the output it would produce would have such columns as this produces:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Employees'
```

Now I need something like this but it must work with far more complex selects like this one for example.

```
select e.EmployeeId,e.EmployeeName, et.type, et.IsPermanent
from Employee e
inner join EmployeeType et 
  on e.EmployeeId = et.EmployeeId
```

Problem is that this can be any select query and I don’t know what the user will type into my app. I just need a way to get column info from anything.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? What kind of "column info" are you looking for? The names of the selected columns should be present in the result. Which database system do you use?

Comment: Something like this: SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Employees' But on any join of tables not just one single table. I think Microsoft sql database

Comment: And what's wrong with using exactly that given query? Also, you should know which database system your application is using

Comment: Problem is that it only returns info from one table. I need something that can return this same info but form much more complex selects than just one table. I mean joins etc...

Comment: Give us an example like this: If we have Table1(col_1 int, col2 date) and Tabl2(col2 date, col3 varchar(200)). What results you expect ?

Comment: I edited my question to make it more understandable, hope it will help

Comment: Depending on API you have different options. "describe".

Comment: When an app (be it Java, C#, whatever) sends a query to the DBMS, the DBMS not only sends back the result values, but also the column data types of that result, so the app knows whether a value represents a string, a date, a number, ... So, what is it that you think you must handle yourself in your app? What programming language and libraries do you use to access the database?

Comment: What application language are you using?

Comment: I am using CSharp

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I luckily solved my issue using SqlDataReader:

```
var columnNames = Enumerable.Range(0,reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetName).ToList();

var columnFieldTypes = Enumerable.Range(0, reader.FieldCount).Select(reader.GetFieldType).ToList();
```